# Using Pandas Dataframe in TensorFlow - X and Y values

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'am trying to follow this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G7oolm0jU8I&list=PLIivdWyY5sqJxnwJhe3etaK7utrBiPBQ2&index=3

But since he is importing with old tf functions and he is already importing an heavily altered .csv file, I tried to import the original one, alter it with pandas and then use it in linear-model.

This is what I did:

```
filename = "iris.data"
data = pd.read_csv(filename, names=["feature1", "feature2", "feature3", "feature4", "target"])
data['target'] = data['target'].str.replace('Iris-setosa','1')
data['target'] = data['target'].str.replace('Iris-virginica','2')
data['target'] = data['target'].str.replace('Iris-versicolor','3')
data['target'] = pd.to_numeric(data['target'])

training_data: pd.DataFrame= data.loc[:120]
eval_data: pd.DataFrame = data.loc[120:150]
```

Which gives me two pandas dataframe. Now I try to use the training_data in TF:

```
feature1 = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("feature1")
feature2 = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("feature2")
feature3 = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("feature3")
feature4 = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("feature4")

feat_cols = [feature1, feature2, feature3, feature4]
input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
    x=training_data[['feature1', 'feature2', 'feature3', 'feature4']],
    y=training_data['target'],
    batch_size=128,
    num_epochs=1,
    shuffle=True,
    queue_capacity=1000,
    num_threads=1,
    target_column='targetx'
)

classifier = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(
    feature_columns=feat_cols,
    n_classes=3,
    model_dir="/tmp/iris_model")

classifier.train(input_fn=input_fn, steps=1000)
```

This gives me an error because the x and y values are obviously wrong but I can't figure out what they mean, because the documentation about them is short to non existent. Some posts state that x stand for feature columns and y for labels. But this doesn't help me, because coming from pandas I know that labels are the names for the columns, but what are feature columns, bc for me it means the same?!

Could please somebody elaborate what x and y means.

Here is the error:

```
TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'dict'> to Tensor. Contents: {'feature1': <tf.Tensor 'random_shuffle_queue_DequeueUpTo:6' shape=(?,) dtype=float64>, 'feature2': <tf.Tensor 'random_shuffle_queue_DequeueUpTo:7' shape=(?,) dtype=float64>, 'feature3': <tf.Tensor 'random_shuffle_queue_DequeueUpTo:8' shape=(?,) dtype=float64>, 'feature4': <tf.Tensor 'random_shuffle_queue_DequeueUpTo:9' shape=(?,) dtype=float64>, 'target': <tf.Tensor 'random_shuffle_queue_DequeueUpTo:10' shape=(?,) dtype=int64>}. Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

Comment: "*This gives me an error*" is hardly helpful for anyone; what error *exactly*? Please post the full error trace.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to be using a dataframe?
Try converting them into an array beforehand:

```
array = data.values
x = array[:,0:3]
y = array[:,4]
```

But you should also check out keras for [this kind of work](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multi-class-classification-tutorial-keras-deep-learning-library/).

Comment: When I try to use an array I get: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'

Comment: You are getting that error because 'index' is an attribute of a list, not of a numpy array. You might want to use `np.where()` for your approach

Comment: Then I get: `'tuple' object has no attribute 'copy'`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce the error you mention. I'm using TF 1.13.1. This is the error I got when I ran your code:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: assertion failed: [Labels must <= n_classes - 1]
```

So, I just changed 1,2,3 to 0,1,2. Then the program runs without errors.

```
data['target'] = data['target'].str.replace('Iris-setosa','0')
data['target'] = data['target'].str.replace('Iris-virginica','1')
data['target'] = data['target'].str.replace('Iris-versicolor','2')
```

You can get the csv files used in the tutorial from here:

http://download.tensorflow.org/data/iris_training.csv

http://download.tensorflow.org/data/iris_test.csv

I'm using Tensorflow '1.13.1'. And the example works fine albeit with warnings to use tf.data.

https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/yufengg/a6dff912ab48f7a273f5704ad9ab1311

Tutorial for using tf.data. Also, explains how to create feature columns from iris csv data.

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/premade_estimators

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/samples/core/get_started/iris_data.py

Comment: Thank you for all this infos, but it doesn't exactly help me with my problem: to use a pandas df in tf.

Comment: I updated the answer after trying your code snippet. Please check.